# PPTPD-server split tunnel

Tags: linux, vpn, linux-networking, pptp, split-tunnel

Normally the client has to set up the VPN connection to be a split tunnel (not routing internet traffic trough the tunnel, but still have access to local resources), but is this possible to define on the server side?

I have a VPN server, which sole purpose is to give access to local resources. Therefore it is unnecessary for internet traffic to be routed trough the tunnel.

How can I prevent clients from having to specifically set up a split tunnel? It would be easier if it was just defined on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding the `nodefaultroute` option in your pptp server's options lists (and also remove `defaultroute` option), which will prevent the client's to set default gateway to pptp server, when connected.

> nodefaultroute
>
> Disable the defaultroute option. The system administrator who wishes to 
>   prevent users from creating default routes with pppd can do
>   so by placing this option in the /etc/ppp/options file.

Ref: https://ppp.samba.org/pppd.html